# powershell -replace only replaces last match

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I need help with this regex. I get a string like below. I want something like

ServerName: AdminServer  RUNNING
ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING

```
$rv="xxx ServerName: AdminServer  RUNNING  xxxx ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING xxx"
$rv -replace ".*(ServerName: [A-Za-z0-9]*.*[RUNNING|SHUTDOWN])",'$1'
ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING xxx
```

With what I have now I only get the last match?

EDIT:

```
$rv="xxx ServerName: AdminServer  RUNNING  xxxx ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING 
$rv -replace ".*(ServerName: [A-Za-z0-9]*.*RUNNING|SHUTDOWN)",'$1'
```

gives

```
ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING xxx
```

not

```
ServerName: AdminServer  RUNNING
ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING
```

EDIT2:
Turns out I have over simplified this. The string looks more like this:

```
$rv='XXX rtification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>
Successfully Connected to Node Manager.
ServerName: SasTTpcAdminServer

RUNNING

Successfully disconnected from Node Manager.
Connecting to Node Manager ...
Successfully Connected to Node Manager.
ServerName: XXXServicesServer1

RUNNING

Successfully disconnected from Node Manager.'
```

Comment: Right the [] are wrong - but it still is not right
`$rv -replace ".*(ServerName: [A-Za-z0-9]*.*[RUNNING|SHUTDOWN])",'$1'`

RUNNING xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not necessarily an ideal approach, it will "work" after fixing some issues:

1. `[RUNNING|SHUTDOWN]` is a character calss, not an aliteration. Switch it to `(?:RUNNING|SHUTDOWN)`
2. The `.*`s matches *too greedily*. Use `.*?` instead.

Final:

```
$rv -replace ".*?(ServerName: [A-Za-z0-9]*.*?(?:RUNNING|SHUTDOWN))", '$1'
```

Notice how it doesn't match the last bit .. however, there is likely a better solution to this (note that this uses the previously discussed fixes and some tweaks of my own):

```
$r = [regex]::matches($rv,"(ServerName:.*?\w+.*?(?:RUNNING|SHUTDOWN))")
$r[0].Value
# -> ServerName: AdminServer  RUNNING
```

Then we can map the capture group values into something simpler:

```
$r | % { $_.Value }
# -> 
# ServerName: AdminServer  RUNNING
# ServerName: ServicesServer1  RUNNING
```

Comment: That is Great! I had no idea that i would be that complex. Could you point me to an explaination of [regex]::matches?

Comment: It's just [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx); see also [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

Comment: For the "new" input, consider something like `^(ServerName:.*?)$` and use [RegexOptions.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

Comment: I give you the answer even though @Christian came up with a one-liner afterwards

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 [regex]::Matches($rv, "(ServerName: [A-Za-z0-9]*.*?(?:RUNNING|SHUTDOWN))") | select -expa value
```

or

```
($rv | select-string -Pattern "(ServerName: [A-Za-z0-9]*.*?(?:RUNNING|SHUTDOWN))" -AllMatches ).matches | select -expa value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rv -replace '[\s\S]*?(ServerName: \w+)[\s\S]*?((RUNNING|STOPPED).*\n)[\s\S]*?(?(?=ServerName)[\s\S]*?|.*$)', '$1 $2'
```

worked fine for me. :)